# codeigniter 3 database connection with third party Database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I am trying to connect database using codeigniter 3 but i am facing this issue anybody please help.

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message:
>   mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host
>   'pd8344-001.privatesql' (2) Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php Line
>   Number: 202 Backtrace: File: /var/www/html/importdb/index.php Line:
>   292 Function: require_once

And

> A Database Error Occurred Unable to connect to your database server
>   using the provided settings. Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php Line
>   Number: 500

here is my db setting in config file.

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'pd8344-001.privatesql',
'port'     => '3306',
'username' => '****',
'password' => '****',
'database' => 'db_name',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => TRUE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,//(ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Your hostname should be IP address or domain name or localhost.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. one thing my client only get phpmyadmin from hosting provider so there is a need for ip , domain or server name will work like for hostname?

Comment: When you login in phpadmin, somewhere on the top or eventually on the right of root/main page should be server name. Very often DB server is on the same server where files are, so could be working with `localhost`.

Comment: yes , on the top server name is same that i set in connection. but script and phpmyadmin is not on the same server. so what you suggest?

Comment: Is there some IP too?

Comment: no , there is no ip address

Comment: Best way is to ask support for provided service (MySQL DB) because without that information you won't be able to connect to DB.

Comment: ok guys, thanks for your support I will ask from hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Set the hostname in your database config file to the actual hostname of the database server and it should then work as expected.

A valid hostname is either a domain, or IP. Rather than `pd8344-001.privatesql` I would expect to see something more like `pd8344-001.privatesql.com` for example.

If you are having trouble finding the hostname and your host provides a phpMyAdmin interface, log into your phpMyAdmin account and copy the current URL with everything after (and including) "/phpMyAdmin" removed.

E.g.

```
pd8344-001.privatesql.com/phpMyAdmin?sess=213123123123&stuff=21314123123&more=sadhfasdjhgfasd
```

You should get

```
pd8344-001.privatesql.com
```

Comment: yes , i did it but now i am facing this issue "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 347"

Comment: Contact your host and ask what your database hostname is

Comment: can you please make sure it is host problem so that i can discuss with him?

Comment: Its not a problem with the host. The problem is that you do not have the correct hostname for the database server. It's like trying to get to a website without the domain name