# CodeIgniter: Not stable database connection

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two hosts

- web host ( **A server** )
- database server ( **B server** )

Connection between them is not stable. I don't believe it is connectivity via servers problem, because I can reach that database and website anytime I want from my local device. What could be wrong?

Specification:

- MySQL 5.5.52 ( **B server** )
- CodeIgniter 3.1.0 ( **A server** )

What was done:

- Opened port for MySQL in **B server**;
- Granted full privileges for user to connect from **A server** IP to database;
- Edited `my.cnf` file - added **B Server's** external IP (in config value: `bind-address`)

Error Msg;

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message:
>   mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'IP' (4)

Comment: what does not stable mean

Comment: One time it works, one time it says that can't connect to database

Comment: well show the actual error message you receive from the server

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '*IP*' (4)
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

I just simply selecting value, one time it returns result, one time it returns that error.

Comment: please see [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35852956/1816093) , [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35126910/1816093) , [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35255709/1816093) ,

Comment: My database configurations are okey, because I can simply connect from my local device. Done everything like in 1st link.

Comment: Also, find out that it's like period of time (like timeout), after which I try to run select sentence and it runs without error, but after page refresh same error displays (just like, when I try to run that sentence twice, sometimes three, four times, it fails)